# Laravel 9 Cron job does not run

Tags: laravel, cron

I have a Laravel 9 project. I need to run some jobs through Cron. Following the documentation, I have updated `app/console/Kernel.php` as given here (Testing to update the notification table):

```php
namespace App\Console;

use App\Models\notification;
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();

        $schedule->call(function () {
            $result = notification::where('id', 1)
               ->update(['read' => 1]);

            $notification = new notification([
                'client_id' => 3,
                'user_id' => 2,
                'client_post_id' => 750,
                'create_user_id' => 3,
                'notification' => '  System has created a notification'
            ]);

            $ok = $notification->save();
        })->everyMinute();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

When I run the `php artisan schedule:list`, I do see that the cron job is running:

```
Home@MacBook-Air cota % php artisan schedule:list       

* * * * *  Closure at: app/Console/Kernel.php:29 
 ............................................ Next Due: 42 seconds from now
```

However, I don't see any changes in the database table. (When I run these commands in terminal through tinker, it works, so the commands are good)

Is there any I am missing or I need to configure something to enable the writing into database through Cron job.

Also, where can I see the cron errors?

Comment: The command `php artisan schedule:list` doesn't run the schedule, it shows what commands will be run and when. Do you have a `CRON` task that actually runs it? See the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler, it should be something like `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` in a CRON Tab or via `php artisan schedule:work`

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for your help. I tried the   php artisan schedule:work command and it works!

Comment: No problem! Make sure to read the full documentation next time; you were incorrectly assuming that `schedule:list` was doing something more than just reporting the status of your Scheduler 

Comment: @TimLewis  Thanks. I read the documentation and tried the 'crontab -e' and entered the cron command that you have provided on my production server, and it worked. I believe that using cron command is better as it involves no manual interaction, particularly after the server is restarted.

Comment: You're correct! On a server, setting up a `crontab` to run this command is the correct step. The `php artisan schedule:work` is a background process that mimics a CRON setup, and is intended for local use, as most people don't have cron running locally by default.

Answer (score -1):

you may use the

> php artisan schedule:work

Artisan command. This command will run in the foreground and invoke the scheduler every minute until you terminate the command

Comment: Didn't downvote, but questions and answers that boil down to a non-reproducible problem (i.e. not running the correct command) are generally closed and/or deleted instead of being answered, as they are unlikely to help others on Stackoverflow.